# how to Select from DropDownList based on Data retrieved form DB in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, database, drop-down-menu

I wanna use DropDownList to choose an Item pf a list which comes from DB. and I don't want to put AutoPostBack="True" since it refreshes the page and don't wait until the user click the submit button. but it seems nothing changes its value when I select different Item, what should I do? thanks

Comment: how do you do the submit? even without AutoPostBack, once you select an item a server side button click should be able to capture currently selected item if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to check postback, 
so I changed to this and it worked.

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Hashtable reciever = new Hashtable();                
            DBController db = new DBController();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = db.GetMyFriends(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["user"].Value));
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                reciever.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["MemId"].ToString()),row["Name"].ToString());
            }
            recivers.DataSource = reciever;
            recivers.DataValueField = "Key";
            recivers.DataTextField = "Value";
            recivers.DataBind();
        }
```